# Replacing multiple strings with the same string replacement

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-update

Been looking all over for this and I don't think nested replace is the answer. I have a list of email address that I need to keep unique, but I need to make them all fake for testing.  So my idea was to just replace the '.com', '.net', '.org' and so on to '.mydomain.com'. But there are a LOT of endings in total.

I realized I could just remove the @ and add '@mydomain.com' to the end, but now I also want to figure out how to solve this particular problem.

Instead of doing:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE Customer
  SET Email=REPLACE(Email, '.com','.mydomain.com')
where email not like '%.mydomain.com%'
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

for each case '.com', '.net', '.org'........

is there a way to say, replace all of these ('.com', '.net', '.org') with '.mydomain.com' in one statement?

something like this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
UPDATE Customer
  SET Email=REPLACE(Email, (in ('.com', '.net', '.org')),'.mydomain.com')
where email not like '%.mydomain.com%'
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle, just run 3 separate queries.

```
update Customer set email = replace(email, '.com', '.mydomain.com') where email not like '%.mydomain.com%';
update Customer set email = replace(email, '.net', '.mydomain.com') where email not like '%.mydomain.com%';
update Customer set email = replace(email, '.org', '.mydomain.com') where email not like '%.mydomain.com%';
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some simple function I wasn't aware of, but since there isn't I agree with this. And using excel it's easy to create an update script for reach of the 100+ endings. Thanks!

Comment: NP. See [acceptIng answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work.

```sql
UPDATE Customer
  SET Email (case 
      where CHARINDEX(Email, '.com') > 0 then REPLACE(Email, '.com','.mydomain.com')
      where CHARINDEX(Email, '.net') > 0 then REPLACE(Email, '.net','.mydomain.com')
      where CHARINDEX(Email, '.org') > 0 then REPLACE(Email, '.org','.mydomain.com')
      end)
where email not like '%.mydomain.com%'
```

May `CHARINDEX` can be replaced by any function that verify if a string contain a substring.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have nested replace statements:

```
update Customer set email = replace(replace(email, '.com', '.mydomain.com'), '.net', '.mydomain.com')
```

You can go on to as many levels as you want. You can even generate the replace statement dynamically.

Another possible solution is to use a stored procedure.

Comment: Quote from the OP: "...  I don't think nested replace is the answer."

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UPDATE ... FROM` to join a derived table of the TLDs you want to replace. (You can also join a "real" table with the TLDs if you have one.)

```
UPDATE c
       SET c.email = replace(c.email, concat('.', tld.tld), '.mydomain.com')
       FROM customer c
            INNER JOIN (VALUES ('com'),
                               ('org'),
                               ('net')) tld (tld)
                       ON c.email LIKE concat('%.', tld.tld)
       WHERE c.email NOT LIKE '%.mydomain.com';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73f2e685ac4fd30853bf7f24b38f4a7b)

It won't solve the problem though that, if a substring that matches a TLD is in the string somewhere else as at the end, this substring also gets replaced. But probably that's not an issue here.